# Endless output with var_dump and script execution time

Tags: php

Why doesn't PHP script execution time limit output time of an endless `var_dump`? This will crash Firefox on my system (DragonFlyBSD) because it eats up gigabytes of memory. On Ubuntu it crashes Apache.

**Edit**: I did a `var_dump` of an object with cycle references, without xdebug. This was on a framework I don't know so well.

**Edit 2**: Use this option to limit Apache output: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody

Comment: And what do you try to `var_dump()`, that *it eats up gigabytes of memory* google or what?

Comment: That happens when you try to vardump your torrent directory lol. Anyway, whatever you are trying to `var_dump` here, it's definitely too big and constructed wrong.

Comment: @Rizier123 Oops, sorry, will edit. I accidentally var_dump an object with cycle references.

Comment: The cycles do not affect `var_dump()`. It detects them and prints `*RECURSION*`. There is no endless output with `var_dump()`. It is just a big text that takes a lot to transfer and display. The running time of `var_dump()` is not that big.

Comment: @axiac This is `var_dump` with out xdebug, so I think you might be wrong.

Comment: @OlleHärstedt Well, I tested it both ways, with and without xdebug, before writing my comment. `var_dump()` with xdebug doesn't print `*RECURSION*` but `...` instead. So I know I am not wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

var_dumping an large object will take centuries until PHP print in the screen.
Thus, the commitment between the objects is part of a return of the management process in the long run expected script you are taking it.

Comment: OK, so can I limit the general process time of PHP via apache? To prevent giant outputs.

Comment: If PHP stops before printing on the screen, you won't see anything. It won't print only a part of your object.